# How to split HTML text node consisting AngularJS tag in Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I am having text like

```
abcd = "{{complaint}} abcd efc'k , star {{ovservation}} agagag"
```

Wanted to split based on AngularJS tags in Python.

Output would be

```
["abcd efc'k , star", "agagag"]
```

I am using `re.split()`.

Comment: no @Kasra....... OP is correct..

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yep I see, good job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split according to the text surrounded by two curly braces.

```
>>> abcd = "{{complaint}} abcd efc'k , star {{ovservation}} agagag"
>>> [i.strip() for i in re.split(r'\{\{.*?\}\}', abcd) if i]
["abcd efc'k , star", 'agagag']
>>> [i.strip() for i in re.split(r'(\{\{.*?\}\})', abcd) if i]
['{{complaint}}', "abcd efc'k , star", '{{ovservation}}', 'agagag']
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. 
Can you please help me to get output like this. 
<code>[{{complaint}},"abcd efc'k , star", {{ovservation}},"agagag"]</code>

Comment: `[i.strip() for i in re.split(r'(\{\{.*?\}\})', abcd) if i]`